# Скрипты на Андроиде?

Tags: python, android, javascript

Есть ли способ запускать скрипты на Андроиде, например, JavaScript или Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть возможность установить [sl4a](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/), там и питон, и перл, и пхп...